# View/Stored procedure for query returning dynamic column Names

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I have a Query that returns the values that I need but the columns in the Query are not actual database columns or columns of any tables. They are jsut what I named them in Query based on a condition. Now I want to show this in a datagrid and export them to Excel from my .NET web Application. I am sure I can create a View but will that pose a problem when I try to access the column as they are not the actual column names of a table?

Or should I go with stored procedure? I am not sure which is more easier and maintainable.

Here's my query below.

```
    SELECT
    c.AttributeValue as ProjectName
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.AttributeValue = 'Active' THEN c.REQUESTID END) as Active
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.AttributeValue = 'Awaiting IPN' THEN c.REQUESTID END) as AwaitingIPN
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.AttributeValue = 'Awaiting LPID' THEN c.REQUESTID END) as AwaitingLPID
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.AttributeValue = 'DE review Completed' THEN c.REQUESTID END) as DEReviewCompleted
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.AttributeValue = 'Info complete' THEN c.REQUESTID END) as InfoComplete
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.AttributeValue = 'IPN added' THEN c.REQUESTID END) as IPNAdded
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.AttributeValue = 'New' THEN c.REQUESTID END) as New
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.AttributeValue = 'Pending DE review' THEN c.REQUESTID END) as PendingDEReview
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.AttributeValue = 'Pending Info' THEN c.REQUESTID END) as PendingInfo
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.AttributeValue = 'Pending Validation' THEN c.REQUESTID END) as PendingValidation
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.AttributeValue = 'Validation Completed' THEN c.REQUESTID END) as ValidationCompleted
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN s.AttributeValue in('Active','Validation Completed','Awaiting IPN','Awaiting LPID','DE review Completed',
    'Info complete','IPN added','New','Pending DE review','Pending Info','Pending Validation') THEN c.REQUESTID END) as TotalRequestsPendingICLUpload
FROM
    Request t
    LEFT JOIN RequestAttributes c
    ON t.RequestID = c.RequestID
    AND c.AttributeID = 8218
    LEFT JOIN RequestAttributes s
    ON t.RequestID = s.RequestID
    AND s.AttributeID = 8265
    WHERE c.AttributeValue IS NOT NULL and c.AttributeValue <> '' AND t.ClosedDate IS NULL
GROUP BY
    c.AttributeValue
```

Comment: You are assigning column aliases which is what you will use in your query. i.e. `select AwaitingIPN from myView` Unless you are going to pass in different request and attribute ID's i don't see why you'd want a procedure over a view here.

Comment: Yeah that's why I created a view in my db but I want to confirm if that's the right way to do it. So in my term model can I directly query my view.awaitingipn to get the field in data table?

Comment: Yes you would use the name of the column you provided in your view.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

A view appears as a table to an external resource.  You should have no problems using the view rather than the tables directly.

Regarding your view, you should change your join between T & C to an inner join.  Every T value will require a C value based on your WHERE clause.  That is functionally equivalent to an inner join.  If you leave it as a left join, the intent of the script is more confusing to maintain and can lead to inefficient query plans by the compiler.

Also, since you not are using T for anything except filtering C, you should move T into a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT  ...
FROM  RequestAttributes AS c
LEFT JOIN RequestAttributes AS s
ON t.RequestID = s.RequestID
WHERE  c.AttributeValue <> '' 
    AND s.AttributeID = 8265
    AND c.AttributeID = 8218
    AND EXISTS (SELECT  1 FROM  Request AS t WHERE  t.ClosedDate IS NULL AND t.RequestID = c.RequestID)
GROUP BY c.AttributeValue;
```

Rather than hardcode the magic numbers into your view, you should consider a table-valued function so you can pass the s & c attribute IDs in.